# How can I force __repr__() instead of _repr_html_() in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

If defined, the `_repr_html_()` method is used in Jupyter notebooks to represent objects. However, what if I wanted the plain `__repr__()` method instead? Is there a setting that turns of HTML repr? I do not want to write `repr(obj)` all the time.

Comment: "I do not want to write repr(obj) all the time." As they say, "explicit is better than implicit". You can force formatting the `repr` of the string into another string, e.g. `f'{obj!r}'`, but that hardly seems any better. You can possibly subclass whatever it is and make its `_repr_html_` redirect to `__repr__`, but I can't verify that it would work. Or maybe you could find some configuration option in Jupyter. But also: "simple is better than complex". Why not just *temporarily try running the code with something else*?

Comment: I did not try to write an answer because it is not clear to me exactly what the issue is with "writing `repr(obj)` all the time", and it's not clear to me what sorts of options would be acceptable instead.

Comment: As to why I do not want to write `repr(obj)`, I'm writing a tutorial and the assumption is that people work in a standard Python REPL. Therefore, my notebook needs to show the same output that they are seeing.

Comment: *"Or maybe you could find some configuration option in Jupyter."* – That's exactly what I'm looking for.